# Python problem to install discord.py using pip

Tags: python, pip, installation, discord, discord.py

I tried installing the `discord.py` module according to the instructionsbut my code don't execute.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Cyril/Desktop/@Dev/pyDiscord/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import discord
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord'
```

I tried to install all the requirements, and they are all installed. When i try all the command like:

```
pip install discord.py
```

or

```
python -m pip install discord.py
```

I get various message, but at the start of all the output are:

```
Requirement already satisfied:
```

My IDE is Visual Studio Code. `pip` is on the last version (20.1.1). My Python version is 3.8.3.

Comment: When you do `pip --version` does it show your 3.8.3 version? Are you using virtual environments?

Comment: If you have various versions of python check that you're installing to the correct version

Comment: DaveStSomeWhere Yes i have this PIP version and no i dont user virtual env ; Mafia yes my python looks like good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `cmd` and run this command:

```
py -3 -m pip install -U discord.py
```

The message `Collecting discord.py` should appear if discord module is not (properly) installed on your machine, otherwise, try running `cmd` as an **administrator** and do the same installation process, if the error still exists, try reinstalling python

Run this program to check whether the error is fixed or not:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('pong')
try:
    bot.run('token')
except discord.errors.LoginFailure: 
    print("invalid token")
#remove the exception block if you have a valid token
```